# SQL binary tree traversal

Tags: sql

How can i get all child nodes from sql table? (MemberJoiners table on pict)
Table structure:

```
ParentID LeftChildID righChildID
```

Here is pict:[image]

Comment: ok, this is my fault. My Db is SQL SERVER 2008

Comment: You can use recursive queries for that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Do you mean all child nodes or all descendents of a given parent?

Comment: All child nodes of given parent.(Child of child nodes and so fourth...)

Comment: Do you have a depth limit? If so, you can do it without recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursive queries work, as pointed out by @Sayem.  However, I would suggest a little bit of a redesign to use a Modified Pre-order Traversal technique.  Sounds fancy, but [this article](http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/) explains it well.

If you are read-heavy, then it is a really fast technique.